# How to install adobe flash professional cs5.5?

Tags: flash, adobe

I downloaded Adobe flash professional cs5.5 on ubuntu 12.10 with wine 1.4.It creates the installer clearly.But when I typed the serial key and continued installation,It is showing me an error message.Tell me what to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the wine [AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21127), you can't just install Adobe Flash Professional CS5. There is a workaround, but the app has only got a silver rating with wine. However,  [Flash Professional CS6](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26404) works good, but you still need to install it on Windows first, then copy the files to linux.